# When at least one projectile out of a group hits the target, how to call a function only once per group?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, projectile

When a shotgun fires a group of pellets, and let's say 1 or 20 pellets hit the target: how do I call a function only once per accurate shot, instead of once per pellet collision?

When using OnCollisionEnter on the projectile or on the target itself, the method gets called for each individual pellet collision.

Should I use an event for this problem? How would I do this?

Edit:
Ah, I forgot to edit this once I figured it out. I think some people might've misunderstood my problem.

Comment: you can add the shutgun reference, or any other game object to the pellet script. or you can use events, delegates, static methods, etc. it's your call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever stumbles upon this, the way I've done it is by generating a unique ID for each shot of a weapon, and assigning it to each projectile inside that shot. Then any projectile that hits the target will check if that unique ID has called the method yet or not. So this way when you fire 1 shot which has 20 projectiles, each projectile that hit the target will do damage to the target, but only knock it back once, no matter how many projectiles hit.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `OnCollisionEnter` find `ContactPoint.points`.

Now you can use your **accuracy** calculation here and find out which one is perfect.

If perfect, then call function else not.